# Visual Studio runs wrong file

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

As you can see in the screenshot, I have two files. I want to run source2.cpp, but VS runs source1.cpp. How can I make it run the file I want? I'm using VS 2013.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Um, if they're both part of the same project, they will be both compiled to separate object files, then linked together into one exectuable... Also, why have you tagged your question C#?

Comment: Sigh: please show the **whole** screenshot.

Comment: So there is no way to run them separately?

Comment: @ShaulAharon yes there is, but you need to put them in different projects. Show the whole screenshot.

Comment: I can see you have `main()` in `Source2.cpp`, right? And you want it to run  instead of `main` in `Source1.cpp`, right? Is yes and yes, then you have to define another entry point for the linker: *select project properties->Configuration Properties->Linker->Advanced and on the right pane of the dialog is a place for the name of the entry point function* (from [here](http://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/798972-how-change-entry-point-main-c-langauge)).

Comment: This sounds eerily familiar....

Comment: @MartinJames And it even has the exact same title. What a coincidence!

Comment: I did! I taw a puddy tat as plain as he could be.

Comment: @MartinJames It's not really fair to say his old question, which was downvoted heavily and closed as unclear, is a duplicate. Best think of this as attempt number two at asking the question.

Answer (score 4):

cpp files are simply source files, and are not an executable. Source files are added to a project and compiled together. All of the source in all of the included files will be added to the resulting assembly or executable you are building. You run an executable, you don't run a .cpp file. Just like you don't run a .h file or a .vcxproj or anything else. Only executables are run.

.EXE files are executables.

Answer (score 0):

Remove 'source1.cpp' from the project.
Add 'source2.cpp' to the project.

Rebuild the project.

Fix all the bugs from #includes etc that no longer work:)